# How can I get the word "Chapter" to be typeset in chapter headings (scrbook)?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script

I am using the `scrbook` class, and I want the word "Chapter" to appear in the heading of the chapter, instead of just the number. How can I do it? I tried

```
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter}
```

but that does not work.

Comment: No need for that. Just use `chapterprefix=on` as option for the document class. It is described in Chapter 3 of the »[KOMA-Script](http://texdoc.net/pkg/koma-script)« user guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MWE

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=on]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]